# How to define a shared table inside a function?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to define a shared table inside a function, It works if I use share(table,`sharedTable). I wonder why can't I put the “share table as sharedTable” statement in a function?

Answer (score 0):

The shared table can be defined inside the function by the following method:

```py
share(table(1:0, `updateTime`maxQty`maxDollarVolume`sumDollarVolume`count, [TIMESTAMP, INT, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, INT]), "outputTable")
```

Regarding the above problems, the reasons are as follows:

The share statement is executed at compile time, and the share function is executed at runtime. Therefore, the share statement is required to be globally visible, not in a function definition.

At the same time, the share table supports concurrent writing.